# Angular tour of heroes, How is the ID added in the addHero method?

Tags: javascript, angular, object, observable

in Agular's tour of hero official tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

when calling the addHero method, only the hero's name property is passed, but somehow a new hero object with id property is created. 
I may be missing something, but where did the id property come from?

Comment: stuck at the same place... upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This angular application uses [angular-in-memory-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api) package that intercepts all http requests and hides some features under the hood:

```
protected post(...): ResponseOptions {
  const item = this.clone(this.getJsonBody(req));

  if (item.id == undefined) {
    try {
      item.id = id || this.genId(collection, collectionName);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                     generate id
```

https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/25c6a217986695de619feed35851332636769a05/src/in-mem/backend.service.ts#L590-L592